# ¿Como solucionar error ATP2000 .Net MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui

Estoay haciendo una pequeña practica con .Net MAUI, pero al intentar correr la aplicación en mi telefono me marca el siguiente error:

> Error: ATP2000 | El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado (2).

En mi laptop con windows si corre el proyecto pero en el celular no.

Comment: Es un proyecto en particular? puede ser algun tema de tu emulador? el proyecto por defecto funciona?

Comment: Es una practica para empezar a aprender la tecnologia de MAUI, No estoy usando ningun emulador lo quiero correr en mi celular pero ni siquiera lo instala, en windows si corre bien

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5957

Comment: Pero el de ese enlace dice que es un error por poner símbolos como acentos, y que por eso no le corre, pero ya cheque la carpeta y no tiene ningún símbolo como ese.

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, solo me faltaba descargar el SDK build-tools correspondiente.

Answer (score 1):

Solo faltaba descargar el SDK Build-Tools correspondiente.
El cual se hace desde el menu Herramientas -> Android -> Administrador de Android SDK -> Pestaña Herramientas -> Desplegar Android SDK Build Tools -> Elegir la version correspondiente.
Y listo.

Answer (score 0):

A mi tambien me daba ese error pero por mas que descargue el sdk correspondiente y otros por si acaso no me funcionaba, pero lo resolvi cambiando la ruta de mi proyecto por una sin espacios ni acentos: E:\MisProyectos\NombreMiProyecto.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).